# bias reduction when the bias depends on the true parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation

Let's say we estimate a parameter, $\theta$, by $\hat{\theta}$. For this estimator we have the following property that $$\hat{\theta}\to_{p}\theta+f(\theta)$$

where $\to_{p}$ denotes convergence in probability and $f(\theta)$ is a random function indexed by $\theta$. I am now wondering if there is a way to reduce the bias? Let's say, I calculate the expected value of $f(\theta)$ but then it is indexed by $\theta$ hence I cannot subtract this mean from $\hat{\theta}$ to reduce the bias. Is there any way to tackle this problem?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up: You have data from a distribution based on $\theta$. As you increase sample size $n$, the probability to have a certain difference between the true but unknown $\theta$ PLUS an arbitrary (maybe not even continous) function of it $f(\theta)$ and your estimator $\hat{\theta}$ becomes zero.

The point here is that $f(\theta)$ without any given restricitions on $f$ is so arbitrary that it is actually nothing else than a new random variable, say, $\delta=f(\theta)$. Notice that $\theta$ and $\delta$ might or might not be correlated as this depends on the nature of $f$.

If, on the other hand, $f$ was known, you could subsume
$$g(\theta)=\theta+f(\theta)$$
and by the continous mapping theorem
$$\hat{\theta} \overset{p}{\to} g(\theta) \implies g^{-1}(\hat{\theta}) \overset{p}{\to} \theta$$
$g^{-1}(\hat{\theta})$ is then a better estimator of $\theta$ than $\hat{\theta}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree with your general approach and understand that one needs more information on $f$. In fact the situation I have is that $f$ is not continuous and not easily invertible.